# List objects in Google Cloud Storage using the S3 interop API

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

We're currently looking into migrating some objects that we store in S3 to Google Cloud Storage. According to their documentation their XML API should be S3 compatible. Pretty much the only thing we have to do is to change the hostname and access keys. However, when I look at the documentation I don't see the LIST method mentioned anywhere. They seem to support PUT, GET, HEAD and DELETE but not LIST.

Is this true? Seems to completely to defeat the purpose of having a compatibility layer if it almost works. The development resources required to implement that single function feels negligible compared to the difference in value between almost being compatible with S3 and being completely compatible with S3.

Comment: There is no `LIST` *method* but as you see from the answer below, listing objects is `GET`.  Heads up, though, Google apparently didn't bother to support S3 API-compatible multipart uploads or AWS Signature Version 4, so you have to use V2 authorization.  Otherwise, it's reasonably compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To list the objects in a bucket with the XML API you use:

```
GET bucket
```

as documented at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#getbucket

This is the same interface as the S3 bucket listing API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have read more carefully. It was just a bit confusing, since S3 uses the verb "list" in pretty much all of its API libraries.